# При тапе на телефоне на кнопку появляется синий фон с дефектами

Tags: html, css

[image: Дефект у стрелки с анимацией][image: Синий фон при тапе]

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при нажатии на кнопку на телефоне, появляется синий фон у кнопки и у рядом стоящей стрелки. Свойство outline:none; не помогает, а свойство -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); практически не поддерживается браузерами.

Comment: «практически не поддерживается браузерами» — какие из интересующих вас браузеров не поддерживают, например?

Comment: наверное, этот синий фон с потолка берется....по всей видимости у вас имеются конфликтующие стили, которые вылазят наружу при определенных действиях и вам стоит разобраться где в стилях вы используете этот цвет и каким образом он попадает в ваши пугкты меню

Comment: @МихаилРебров, не думаю, что проблема в стилях. Вполне браузер телефона может их подсвечивать.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, я не припомню такого пастельного бирюзового цвета в дефолтной цветовой схеме какого бы то ни было из браузеров. Также этот цвет идеально ложится в палитру шаблона на скриншоте и обладает той же насыщеностью что и другие цвета на скриншоте. Бьюс о заклад - они еще на равном удалении друг от друга на цветовом круге находятся... этот цвет - явно из палитры стилей используемого шаблона.

Comment: просто из-за каких-то косяков в стилях он здесь вылазит наружу

Comment: @OliverPatterson вынужден признать свою неправоту. Я нашел этот шаблон в интернете. И нашел похожий цвет в палитре - но не тот. Указанного цвета в шаблоне я не нашел

Comment: @OliverPatterson вопспроизвести проблему по тапу и удержанию я смог...Но более того...я смог его воспроизвести и на другиз сайтах (в том числе и на stackoverflow). Что даёт полное основание считать что это действительно дефолтный цвет, который используется браузером чтобы выделить элемент, который вы тапнули и удерживаете.

Comment: вот он же на so https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNYy4.png

Comment: относительно `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` он у меня прекрасно работает на других страницах, но не работает  на странице с данным шаблоном